# Xcode systemic crash on open project - how to reset Xcode assistant editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I've ran into an issue where whenever I open the assistant editor (second code panel) in Xcode, it crashes and gives me an option to reopen Xcode.

**Xcode quit unexpectedly**
reading the report,seems that `CVDisplayLink` is to blame

```
Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
```

**Is there a way to reset which class is displayed in the 2nd panel?**

```
Process:         Xcode [508]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [131]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-01-14 12:33:28.087 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          4527 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  444 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      F0403235-5ECB-ADEA-6618-E5526B9FE281

Crashed Thread:  22  CVDisplayLink

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff886c1372 objc_retain + 18
1   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010bf29e59 -[DVTBindingHelper primitiveValueForBinding:] + 88
2   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010bf29d44 -[DVTBindingHelper valueForBinding:] + 48
3   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010bf2379c -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) updateBoundValueForBinding:] + 227
4   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010bf235ec -[DVTBindingHelper observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 252
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010b9d0839 -[DVTObservableObjectProxy setRepresentedObject:] + 561
6   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010cb1a8a6 -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item:] + 280
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865c1439 -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 1573
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865c0c1c -[NSOutlineView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 56
9   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010bf7ed1f -[DVTOutlineView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 54
10  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010cc6287e -[IDENavigatorOutlineView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 54
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865c0b27 -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 47
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865c0a9b -[NSOutlineView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 94
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865bf55e -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 2131
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865af3e3 -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 397
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865af241 -[NSOutlineView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 113
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865addc6 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1269
17  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010cb18db2 -[IDENavigatorOutlineView drawRect:] + 312
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86492064 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 4217
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff864906c1 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1656
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86490ad9 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2704
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648e6f2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 817
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648fa44 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5763
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8648e143 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86489d6d -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 4675
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86453c93 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1830
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff864531cc _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 738
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86a1e901 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke_01208 + 46
40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bf0417 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bf0381 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 369
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb7b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 728
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
44  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8975feb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
45  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8975fc52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8975fae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86450533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8644fdf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff864471a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff863ebbd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff80b537e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d3d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff890c0dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff890c09ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d1686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d0c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bc6233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82cde546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d1686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d0c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bc6233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011328d81a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d3322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87c0af46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d1686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d0c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bc6233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bcb0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d417ee -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82cda1aa -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011735b96b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff851532a1 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 689
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff85152fd7 startIOThread(void*) + 148
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d1686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d0c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff815d217b CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 403
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff81656dc6 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000111ac5fd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000111ac5fd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000111ac5fd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82d3c562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8127fb66 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 118
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814a2bfa JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 90
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814b825f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814059d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814058b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814b825f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814059d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814058b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814b825f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d30fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa35fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814059d4 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 212
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814058b6 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff814b825f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff846d36d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa33ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 22 Crashed:: CVDisplayLink
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff886c136e objc_retain + 14
1   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x0000000119a9521a _cvDisplayLinkCallback + 25
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8515400b CVDisplayLink::performIO(CVTimeStamp*) + 203
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff85153271 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 641
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff85152fd7 startIOThread(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa31772 _pthread_start + 327
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8aa1e1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 22 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x3000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000012450dd80  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x000000012450dc78
  rdi: 0x00007fca0abb7730  rsi: 0x000000012450dd80  rbp: 0x000000012450dc10  rsp: 0x000000012450dbe8
   r8: 0x000000012450dcc8   r9: 0x00007fca0abb7730  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x00007fff70a14250
  r12: 0x00007fca093b46a0  r13: 0x00007fff85153d94  r14: 0x000000012450dc78  r15: 0x0000000119a95201
  rip: 0x00007fff886c136e  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0xffffff80d2cded20
Logical CPU: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the XCode? If crashing is happening every single time, you'd better try to download XCode again

Comment: Reinstalling did not help

Comment: Does it happen always or on a specific project?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this answer on the Apple Dev Forums, and it seemed to work for me:

- Navigate to the folder where your .xcodeproj or . xcworkspace is (for CocoaPods projects)
- Right click on .xcodeproj and select "Show package contents"
- Delete xuserdata folder
- Delete project.xcworkspace
- Repeat for .xcworkspace

Now you can reopen the project or workspace with a blank screen and assistant editor minimized.

[Original answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/937553#937553)